# How to replace a old aspose licence with a new one in vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, aspose, aspose.words

our product is Aspose.Words for .NET

I have read this link http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/wordsnet/Licensing

We had implemented  the aspose license previously (by former developer) in our web application.

this is our code for extracting document .

```
Imports Aspose.Words
Imports System.IO

Public Class Converter
    Public Shared Sub ConvertDocument(ByRef docPath As String, ByRef expPath As String)



        Dim license As New Aspose.Words.License()
        license.SetLicense("Aspose.Words.lic")
        Dim info As Aspose.Words.FileFormatInfo = FileFormatUtil.DetectFileFormat(docPath)

        Dim format As String = info.LoadFormat.ToString().ToLower()

        If Not format = "pdf" Then

            Dim doc As New Aspose.Words.Document(docPath)
            doc.Save(expPath)
        Else

            ' This object will help us generate the document.
            Dim builder As New DocumentBuilder()

            ' You might need to specify a different encoding depending on your plain text files.
            Using reader As New StreamReader(docPath, Encoding.UTF8)
                ' Read plain text "lines" and convert them into paragraphs in the document.
                Dim line As String = Nothing
                line = reader.ReadLine()
                Do While line IsNot Nothing
                    builder.Writeln(line)
                    line = reader.ReadLine()
                Loop
            End Using

            builder.Document.Save(expPath)
        End If

        End Sub
End Class
```

All the setup for aspose was done. After that our aspose license expired and we did not upgraded that for a while. Then we again applied for a temporary license for  30 days.

Now we have the new license for next one year. What do I have to do to apply the new license. Is it ok if I just replace the old licence file ( Aspose.Words.lic)  with the  new license file ( Aspose.Words.lic)

Or do I need to change anything  in the XML file (Aspose.Words.xml) inside Bin folder as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to change anything in XML file or license file. If you're accessing the license from a file, you can simply replace the old file with the new one.

If you're using the license as an embedded resource, you can remove existing resource and then embed the new license file as a resource.

I hope this helps.

Disclosure: I work at Aspose.

Comment: Thanks so much. In the aspose site i have found the information how to apply the license for first time.. but not exactly how to replace...1more question.. I have downloaded the latest dll files.. is it ok to replace the old dll and xml files with new one in the existing system.. the file names are same.. we got net version 4.0.  i can see there are multiple folders such as  net4.0 ; net4.0_AuthenticodeSigned; net4.0_ClientProfile; net4.0_ClientProfile_AuthenticodeSigned. so i am confused which one is the right one. . although  i dont know what is the benefit of latest dll

Comment: Please check the [Installation guide](http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/wordsnet/Installation).
Moreover, net4.0 folder contains assemblies to use with .NET Framework 4.0 and higher. The net4.0_ClientProfile folder contains assemblies to use with .NET Framework 4.0 Client Profile.
All folders with names, such as net2.0_AuthenticodeSigned contain the assembly for the corresponding .NET Framework,
but the assembly is digitally signed with Authenticode. Note that a signed assembly may load slower than without Authenticode. I work with Aspose as Developer Evangelist.